# Difference tabels based on Id and unixtimestamp

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

My table is looking as folowing:

```
unix_timestap   ID  value
1351058019      1   500
1351058029      1   505
1351058039      9   105
1351058049      9   200
1351076620      1   520
```

I would like be able to generate a new column contain the differences between the values per ID between the current value and the first available "past" value. With past I mean that unixtimestamp is not placed in order in the original table.

The output would be:

```
unix_timestap   ID  value    difference
1351058019      1   500      0
1351058029      1   505      5
1351058039      9   105      0
1351058049      9   200      95
1351076620      1   520      15
```

If no previous unix_timestamp exists, the value should be zero.

A Hint/tip would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: A possible solution in my current workflow might be :

Answer (score 0):

if solution still needed

```
select
  t3.unix_timestamp, t3.id, t3.value, ifnull(t3.value - t5.value, 0) as diff
from test1 t3
  join (
        SELECT t1.unix_timestamp, t1.id, max(t2.unix_timestamp) as old_stamp
        FROM `test1` t1
          left join test1 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.unix_timestamp > t2.unix_timestamp
        group by t1.unix_timestamp, t1.id) as t4
  on t3.unix_timestamp = t4.unix_timestamp and t3.id = t4.id
left join test1 t5 on t4.old_stamp = t5.unix_timestamp and t4.id = t5.id
```